# Getters and setters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, datetime, properties

I'm totally new to Python and I'm trying to write a class, which will store only two attributes, one of which is intended to be a number and another a datetime object. Though I'd also like, while storing `date` as a datetime, to initialize and output it using a string like "dd.mm.yyyy". So I go:

```
class MyClass:
    number = None
    date = None

    def __init__(self, params):
        self.number = params["number"]
        self.date = params["date"]

    @property
    def date(self):
        return datetime.datetime.strftime(self.date, '%d.%m.%Y')

    @date.setter
    def date(self, value):
        self.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%d.%m.%Y')

    def get_vars(self):
        return vars(self)
```

But at runtime `@property` points at `self.date` and says: `Expected type 'datetime', got 'str' instead`. How can it ever get a string, when it's meant to be converted to date while setting. Why is this happening? Confused.

For example:

```
>>> MyClass({'number': 42, 'date': '28.12.2017'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 8, in __init__
  File "<string>", line 16, in date
  File "<string>", line 16, in date
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime
```

Comment: Please do include the *full traceback* and the code that creates your `MyClass` instance. I can work out *in this specific, limited case* exactly what must have happened, but a traceback makes it easier for future visitors to see if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `date` for both the `property` object and an instance attribute. Only the property is available (because it is a [*data descriptor*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)), and `self.date` references that property object. The expression `self.date = params['date']` is passing the `param['date']` value to the setter, it is not setting an instance attribute.

Because `param['date']` is evidently a `datetime` object in your case, that means that in the setter `datetime.datetime.strptime(<datetime instance>, '%d.%m.%Y')` is called, which fails. Even if that succeeded, you'd then try to assign that result back to `self.date`, which would call the setter again, ad infinitum. And it is a `datetime` instance either because you passed in a `datetime` value originally, *or* you passed in a string, and the first `.strptime()` call succeeded and now `self.date` is being assigned that `datetime` instance that was just created.

Rename the instance attribute; giving it a leading single underscore is usually the most helpful naming scheme here:

```
class MyClass:
    _number = None
    _date = None

    def __init__(self, params):
        self._number = params["number"]
        self._date = params["date"]

    @property
    def date(self):
        return self._date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

    @date.setter
    def date(self, value):
        self._date = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%d.%m.%Y')

    def get_vars(self):
        return vars(self)
```

I also changed `datetime.datetime.strftime(self._date, '%d.%m.%Y')` (a call to an unbound method) to a method call on `self._date`.

Comment: Now it works and what is more important, I now understand why) Thousand thanks)

Comment: can I ask you one more question? Seems like vars() doesn't use @property when returning the dict with attributes. Is there a way to make it use getters in order to obtain the `data` value in correct  format?

Comment: @Dankevich: no, `vars()` returns the instance attribute dictionary. You'd have to find all attributes on the class (`dir(ype(self))`), test each attribute to see if it is a property, then access the property on the instance, to list those.

Comment: @Dankevich: see [How to list all class properties](//stackoverflow.com/q/1215408)

Comment: it's close, but not exactly what I need here. I'd like to have a dictionary a "key": "value" pairs for all attributes, while this hint only gives me attribute names

Comment: @Dankevich: yes, so use those names with `getattr(self, name)` to get the value.